# jqGrid not displaying data, no errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

OK, this mostly works as far as my PHP action is called and returns the JSON data from the query just fine.  The problem is jqGrid won't display the data.  What am I missing?  I have read every article here and elsewhere on the subject I can find.  This looks like it should work.

HTML:

```
<table id="dsisBaseTable"></table>
<div id=dsisBasePager"></div>
```

Here is my grid definition (the whole JavaScript function):

```
function runGridBaseReport() {
    $('#DSISBaseReportResult').html('<table id="dsisBaseTable"></table>' +
        '<div id="dsisBasePager"></div> ');
    $('#DSISBusy').fadeIn();
    var loc = $('#dsisLocation').val();
    var f = (loc == '') ? '' : loc.substring(0, 1);
    if (f.match(/[A-Z]/) || f.match(/[a-z]/))
    loc = loc.substring(1);

    var dsisParams = {
        mode : 'basereport',
        dsisLocation : loc,
        dsisGuild : $('#dsisGuild').val(),
        dsisNick : $('#dsisNick').val(),
        dsisOccGuild : $('#dsisOccGuild').val(),
        dsisOccNick : $('#dsisOccNick').val(),
        dsisMinLevel : $('#dsisMinLevel').val(),
        dsisMaxLevel : $('#dsisMaxLevel').val(),
        dsisEconomy : $('#dsisEconomy').val(),
        dsisDt : $('#dsisDt').val(),
        dsisDs : $('#dsisDs').val(),
        dsisPr : $('#dsisPr').val(),
        dsisPs : $('#dsisPs').val(),
        dsisMinFleet : $('#dsisMinFleet').val(),
        dsisMaxFleet : $('#dsisMaxFleet').val(),
        dsisCapitol : $('#dsisCapitol').is(':checked'),
        dsisWormHole : $('#dsisWormHole').is(':checked'),
        dsisAeFormat : $('#dsisAeFormat').is(':checked')
        };
    var data = { data: jsonString(dsisParams)};

    $("#dsisBaseTable").jqGrid({
        url: indexUrl + '/basereport',
        datatype: 'json',
        postData: data,
        mtype: 'POST',
        colNames:['Name',
                  'Location',
                  'WH',
                  'Inc',
                  'Eco',
                  'Guild',
                  'Owner',
                  'Level',
                  'Guild',
                  'OccBy',
                  'JG(Log)',
                  'CC',
                  'PH',
                  'DS',
                  'DT',
                  'PS',
                  'PR',
                  'DB',
                  'Fleet',
                  'Days',
                  'Updated By'],
        colModel :[
          {name:'baseName',
            index:'baseName',
            sortable: false,
            width: 50,
            jsonmap: 'row.baseName'},
          {name:'location',
            index:'location',
            width: 50,
            jsonmap: 'row.location'},
          {name:'wh',
            index:'wh',
            width: 50,
            jsonmap: 'row.wormhole'},
          {name:'inc',
            index:'inc',
            align:'right',
            width: 50,
            jsonmap: 'row.income'},
          {name:'eco',
            index:'eco',
            align:'right',
            width: 50,
            jsonmap: 'row.economy'},
          {name:'ownerGuild',
            index:'ownerGuild',
            width: 50,
            jsonmap: 'row.ownerGuild'},
          {name:'ownerNick',
            index:'ownerNick',
            width: 50,
            jsonmap: 'row.ownerNick'},
          {name:'ownerLevel',
            index:'ownerLevel',
            width: 50,
            jsonmap: 'row.ownerLevel'},
          {name:'occGuild',
            index:'occGuild',
            width: 50,
            jsonmap: 'row.occGuild'},
          {name:'occNick',
            index:'occNick',
            width: 50,
            jsonmap: 'row.occNick'},
          {name:'jumpGate',
            index:'jumpGate',
            width: 50,
            jsonmap: 'row.jumpGate'},
          {name:'commandCenter',
            index:'commandCenter',
            width: 50,
            jsonmap: 'row.commandCenter'},
          {name:'photons',
            index:'photons',
            width: 50,
            jsonmap: 'row.photons'},
          {name:'dshield',
            index:'dshields',
            width: 50,
            jsonmap: 'row.dshields'},
          {name:'disruptors',
            index:'disruptors',
            width: 50,
            jsonmap: 'row.disruptors'},
          {name:'pshields',
            index:'pshields',
            width: 50,
            jsonmap: 'row.pshields'},
          {name:'prings',
            index:'prings',
            width: 50,
            jsonmap: 'row.prings'},
          {name:'debris',
            index:'debris',
            width: 50,
            jsonmap: 'row.debris'},
          {name:'fleetSize',
            index:'fleetSize',
            width: 50,
            jsonmap: 'row.fleetSize'},
          {name:'daysOld',
            index:'daysOld',
            width: 50,
            jsonmap: 'row.daysOld'},
          {name:'updatedBy',
            index:'updatedBy',
            sortable: false,
            width: 50,
            jsonmap: 'row.updatedBy'}
        ],
        pager: $('#dsisBasePager'),
        rowNum: $('#basePageSize').val(),
        rowList:[20,30,40,50],
        sortname: 'location',
        sortorder: 'asc',
        viewrecords: true,
        caption: 'Base Report',
        width: 1024,
        height: 300,
        jsonReader : {
            root: "rows",
            page: "page",
            total: "total",
            records: "records",
            repeatitems: false,
            id: "id"
        }
    });
    /*    pages'   => round($totRows/$dsisPageSize),
         'page'    => $dsisPage,
         'total'   => $numRows/$dsisPage,
         'records' => $totRows,
         'rows' */
    $('#DSISBusy').fadeOut();
    $('#DSISBaseReportResult').fadeIn();
    return false;
}
```

This is how I process the request and return the results:

```
public function basereportAction()
{
    try
    {
      $params = $this->_getAllParams();
      //Log::logErr('params:'.print_r($params, true));

      $data = $this->_getParam('data');
      //Log::logErr('Data:'.print_r($data, true));

      $reportParams->request = json_decode($data);
      //Log::logErr('DSIS Obj:'.print_r($obj, true));

      $reportParams->request->dsisPage = $this->_getParam('page');
      $reportParams->request->dsisPageSize = $this->_getParam('rows');
      $reportParams->request->dsisOrderBy = $this->_getParam('sidx');
      $reportParams->request->dsisSortDir = $this->_getParam('sord');

      $base = new Base();
      // $result is a PHP array
      $result = $base->outputDSISReportHtml($reportParams, true);

      $js = json_encode($result);
      Log::logErr('JSON:'.$js);

      $callback = $this->_getParam('callback');

      echo $js;
    }
    catch( Exception $e)
    {
        Log::logErr('DSISReportController::basereport:Error:'.$e->getMessage());
        throw $e;
    }
}
```

This is my data:

```
{
    "total": 0,
    "page": "1",
    "records": 1,
    "rows": [
        {
            "id": 0,
            "row": {
                "baseName": "Stratos",
                "location": "J15:32:53:41",
                "wormhole": "",
                "income": 78,
                "economy": 78,
                "ownerGuild": "CDA",
                "ownerNick": "D-Day 9000",
                "ownerLevel": "17.14",
                "occGuild": "",
                "occNick": "",
                "jumpGate": 0,
                "commandCenter": 1,
                "photons": "0",
                "dshields": "0",
                "disruptors": "0",
                "pshields": "0",
                "prings": "0",
                "debris": 0,
                "fleetSize": "22250",
                "daysOld": 11,
                "updatedBy": 3057
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only error I see in the end of your JSON data ended with "},]}". You should remove the comma before ']'.

After mininal changes to be able to reproduce your test example [your demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/TimBrown.htm) works without any visible problems.

**UPDATED:** [The same demo with new JSON data](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/TimBrown1.htm) works also without any problem. I suppose the error is in the part of code which you not posted here. For exemple, I placed your code inside of `jQuery(document).ready(function () {/*the code*/});`. I have to remove `postData` parameter because its value `data` which you use in your code are not defined. Exactly in the same reason the `indexUrl` variable used in `url` parameter I had to change. The parameter `rowNum:$('#basePageSize').val()` looks also strange and I replaced it to the `rowNum:20`. If you could post the url to the working (not workin) original solution or really full HTML and JavaScript code one could probably help you.

Comment: OK, well that data error is not in my actual data but was a typo.  Does it work with this data:

Comment: I edited the question to include actual data, and it does not work.  Nice to see you got a table from my data but I can't :(

Comment: @Tim Brown: I updated my answer. By the way my example not only shows your data it use more as 90% of your code which you posted.

Comment: The postData is just parameters from a form I pass for the where clause.  The js is in a sep .js file.  It is getting called fine and infact the grid is rendering.  I see the loading sign.  I see that the query executed and ytou see the results..  If there were a way to debug the jqgrid return I would.  It doesn't matter that the html stuff is inside a div does it?  I didn't think so becasue the grid does render and it submits the correct request.

Comment: @Tim Brown: First of all `'<div id=dsisBasePager"></div> '` must be replaced to `'<div id="dsisBasePager"></div> '` (additional opened double-quote for the "dsisBasePager")

Comment: @Oleg, fixed the quote, no change.  Most puzzling

Comment: @Oleg:  You asked about this: rowNum: $('#basePageSize').val().  It returns 20 right now.  In my form I allow this to be set, probably don't need it but I have debugged it and it is 20.

Comment: @Tim Brown: I can suggest you to simplify your code to find the error. My code work. Try to reduce your real code in steps to my code. After the code will run after a step you will see which changes made the problem. After fixing the bug you can continue with your current long code (after the bug fixing of cause). I can not use your code because no HTML code like ("#DSISBaseReportResult" and many other) exist and the code is not full (see `jsonString` function for example). It is also unclear where and how you use the function `runGridBaseReport` which code you published.

Comment: @Oleg.  Yes, I will have to do that.  I will piece all of the code for this function into one page.  That should highlight what I am doing wrong

Comment: @Oleg, I figured out something, it has to do with how I am sending it back from my php action.  Do you have an example of how that is supposed to be done?  I discovered that if I pointed to a text file containing my results like you did that it works.  Also, the php is generating the json correctly because that is what I pasted into the text file.  So it has to be in the transmission back to jqgrid.

Comment: @Tim Brown: It sound very strange. You can compare the response from the server more detailed with the text file. Another reason could be if you server place some wrong information in HTTP headers like "Content-type: text/xml" instead of "Content-type: application/json" or some another wrong information. You can use Fiddler (see http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or Firebug (see http://getfirebug.com/) to see the information. It can also helpful to include `loadError` event handler in the grid.

Comment: @Oleg - it was a server side php error the whole time.  But I did have some errors going into this and now I understand it much better.  Thanks for your help!  Turns out the Zend system was throwing an error back not the results at all.

Comment: @Tim Brown: OK! jqGrid can not place error message inside of the grid. By the way in all grids I recommend have always `loadError` event handler and other handler for row editing, row deleting and so on. Then you can correct display all errors thrown by server. Let me known if you solve the problem.

Comment: @Oleg:  I did solve it.  As soon as I told Zend not to worry about a view page, the data went back and the grid now populates and pages etc.  Thanks much for your help!  For the benefit of others and completeness, I had to add this line to my Zend PHP action:   $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();

Comment: this worked for me thanks   `jQuery(document).ready(function () {/*the code*/});`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. The exhibited jqgrid not return XML. I noticed that the registry database had some special characters like "&". The problem was the browser. Decided as follows by placing the CDATA tag field return in XML:

```
sb.Append ("<cell>"); sb.Append ("<! [CDATA [" + g.Name + "]"); sb.Append ("]> </ cell>");
```